# Spring boot, Hibernate - create-drop uses old schema

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I have spring boot, spring data, hibernate and ms sql,
but with `create-drop` strategy, hibernate creates table based on older implementation of my `@Entity` class.

Entity class as so:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean active = false;

    @Column
    private String activationUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    //getters and setters
}
```

In application.properties, related config:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

But what I see in stdout, once I run my application:

```
2018-03-17 12:08:10.973  INFO 876 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
2018-03-17 12:08:11.473  INFO 876 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table [user]
Hibernate: create table [user] ([id] int identity not null, [account_activationuuid] varchar(255), [account_active] bit not null, [email] varchar(255) not null, [name] varchar(255) not null, [password] varchar(255) not null, [registration_date] datetime2 not null, primary key ([id]))
Hibernate: alter table [user] add constraint UK_gj2fy3dcix7ph7k8684gka40c unique ([name])
2018-03-17 12:08:11.488  INFO 876 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Note that I have deleted `@Column` `registration date`, renamed `accountActivationUUID` to `activationUUID`, and renamed `accountActive` to `active`.

Still, I see old schema in stdout, and it is even like this stored in database.

**So, my questions:**
1) Where does this old schema come from ?
2) Does hibernate have some schema cache ?
3) How to make it generate new schema every time - being exactly representation of `@Entity` classes in my code ?
4) Why does it say to use 2008 dialect in `stdout`, even though I have specified 2012 dialect in `application.properties` ?

I tried invalidating cache in intelj, restarting computer and database, to search for file with old schema definition on hard drive, but none of it worked.

Thanks for any response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and managed to make it work.

Problem was in `pom.xml`, there were some duplicates and some non-existent dependencies, so the run was just falling to latest successful run.
That's how it was using old schema.